# Resolve "Binaries not found" error in Postgres.app

Tags: postgresql

I'm following [these instructions](https://gist.github.com/15Dkatz/321e83c4bdd7b78c36884ce92db26d38) to set up PostgreSQL on my Mac.  Step 3 says I need to click **Initialize**, however there's no such button. Instead, the error message "Binaries not found" is displayed and, if I click the similar **Start** button, the error message "The binaries for this PostgreSQL server were not found" is displayed.  I just downloaded a clean version of Postres.app, so not sure why this wouldn't be working right out of the box.

How to resolve?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Postgres.app's [troubleshooting and support page](https://postgresapp.com/documentation/troubleshooting.html) says the following:

> To fix this issue, make sure that the correct binaries for your server are in
>
> `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/`

without telling you how to actually do that.

One way to do it is to download "Postgres.app with all currently supported PostgreSQL versions" from [Postgres.app's download page](https://postgresapp.com/downloads.html) and replace any other versions you have.  The app will then open without the "Binaries not found" error, assuming that you are only using supported PostgreSQL versions.

Comment: Ugh- it seems like there's something they just need to update with that first Postgres 12 download link, but for the time being your solution did work for me too- thanks!

Answer (score 36):

I found [this answer by stromal](https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues/517#issuecomment-611693914) on Postgres.app's GitHub:

> I solved it by opening up the application's sliding windows, than clicked a new server with the plus icon, than that had initialization button, than clicked initialise than it worked.

[image]

The hidden sidebar slideout was tricky. This solution worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

- Follow the official uninstall [instructions](https://postgresapp.com/documentation/install.html):

> 1. Quit Postgres.app & drag it to the Trash
> 2. Delete the data directory (default location: ~/Library/Application Support/Postgres)
> 3. Delete preferences for Postgres.app by executing the following command: defaults delete com.postgresapp.Postgres2
> 4. Remove the $PATH config for the command line tools (optional): sudo rm /etc/paths.d/postgresapp

- Follow the official installation [instructions](https://postgresapp.com/documentation/install.html).